# Create a regular expression that continues to extract information if and only if the following pattern is met using it as a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, file, python-re

```py
import re

def fun(x):
    match=re.search(r"(?<=hay que) ([\w\s,]+) ([\w\s]+)",x)
    if match:
        for i in re.split(',|y',match[1]):
            with open(f'{i}.txt','w') as file:
                file.write(match[2])


input_text = str(input())
fun(input_text)
```

I need to create a regular expression that continues to match only if there is a comma `,` or `y` after the last one. Extracting the words and creating a text file as indicated in the following examples. And in case these words are followed by `,` or `y`, continue extracting. Then the end of the sentence must be written on one line of each of the .txt files created.

I was having trouble with sentences like for example:

`hay que pintar y decorar las paredes de ese lugar`

generate: pintar.txt, decorar las paredes de ese.txt

write inside each of them: `lugar`

**but it should be:**

generate: pintar.txt, decorar.txt

write inside each of them: `las paredes de ese lugar`

---

Other Examples...

input_sense: `hay que pintar y decorar las paredes y los techos`

generate: pintar.txt, decorar.txt

write inside each of them: `las paredes y los techos`

---

input_sense: `hay que correr, saltar y cantar para llegar alli`

generate: correr.txt , saltar.txt, cantar.txt

write inside each of them: `para llegar alli`

---

input_sense: `yo creo que hay que saltar y correr para ir a ese lugar`

generate: saltar.txt, correr.txt

write inside each of them: `para ir a ese lugar`

---

**IMPORTANT:**  And in case the words listed begin with `no ser|ser|no`

input_sense: `hay que esconderse y ser silenciosos para no ser descubiertos`

generate: esconderse.txt, ser_silenciosos.txt

write inside each of them: `para no ser descubiertos`

---

input_sense: `hay que trabajar, escalar y no temer si quieres llegar a la meta`

generate: trabajar.txt, escalar.txt, no_temer.txt

write inside each of them: `si quieres llegar a la meta`

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first find what should be writen:

```
x = 'hay que trabajar, escalar y no temer si quieres llegar a la meta'
s = re.search(r'( las .*)|( los .*)|( para .*)|( si .*)', x)
content = s.group(0)
```

Then remove what you not want from you string:

```
x = x.replace('hay que','')
x = x.replace(content, '')
x.strip()
```

Replace special words with underscore

```
x = x.replace(' no ', ' no_')
x = x.replace(' ser ', ' ser_')
```

finally split your files names

```
filenames = [f'{name}.txt' for name in re.split(',| y ', x)]
```

Comment: How do I get this "si quieres llegar a la meta" in a variable?

Comment: it is in 'content' variable

Comment: Is it possible to generalize so that what remains in the content variable is what follows the last of the extracted words?, Avoiding doing that totally depends on this:  "( las .*)|( los .*)|( para .*)|( si .*)"

Comment: if you want remove the preposition from content use: `s = re.search(r'(?<= las ).*$|(?<= los ).*$|(?<= para ).*$|(?<= si ).*$', x)` but when you will do `x = x.replace(content, '')` the preposition will be at the end of variable x

Comment: It's not that I want to remove the preposition, but what I want is for the regex to grab the last thing and put it inside variable content. For example, "hay que trabajar, escalar y no temer quieres llegar a la meta", and the variable content = "quieres llegar a la meta", the only criteria I use is to extract everything that follows "no temer"

Comment: you can split your string at the first word after (y or no) for example: `y = re.split(r'((?<= no )\w+|(?<= y )\w+)', x)` where x is your string. Then you can concat all parts of y except the endig `"".join(y[:-1]` to use as your string of things to do, and y[-1] is the string you want to write in your files. This assume that your ending string will never have ' no ' or ' y ' in it.